# ошибка java.util.MissingResourceException

Tags: java

Вот такой код:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String key = sc.next();
    String stringLocale = sc.next();
    while(!key.equals("stop")){
        Locale locale = new Locale(stringLocale);
        ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("resources", locale);
        System.out.println(rb.getString(key));
    }
}
```

по идеи читаем с консоли ключ и локаль, потом, пока не ввели стоп, загружаем пакет ресурсов и печатаем в консоль значение. но падает с `java.util.MissingResourceException`. В корне лежит файл

> resources_ru.properties

Пробовал и *resources/resources_ru.properties*, и *src/resources/resources_ru.properties*, и *src/resources_ru* результат тот же. Что то мне подсказывает что проблема не в пути, хотя могу ошибаться..

Подскажите в чем проблема?

Comment: а что конкретно вы вводите в консоль?

Comment: @SeniorPomidor Перевод ключа. в файле apple = яблоко. Введя apple ru вывод яблоко

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Действительно дело было в classpath. Поместил туда файл .properties и все заработало. И на счет цикла @SergeyGornostaev все верно. Чуть чуть подправил и в принципе все работает.

```
 Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(true){
            String key = sc.next();
            if (key.equals("stop")){
                break;
            }
            String stringLocale = sc.next();
            Locale locale = new Locale(stringLocale);
            ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("resources", locale);
            System.out.println(rb.getString(key));
        }
```

Кстати. Мб кому то пригодится: properties файлы для i18n и l10n(в принципе, любые) должны писаться в кодировке ISO-8859 1, а кириллица записывается в escape-последовательности Unicode. Т.е.: `apple = \u044F\u0431\u043B\u043E\u043A\u043E`

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего, вы получаете эту ошибку потому, что значения с ключом "stop" в файле нет. Кроме того, ваш алгоритм зациклится и будет выводить "Яблоко" бесконечно. Попробуйте так:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

String stringLocale = sc.nextLine();
Locale locale = new Locale(stringLocale);
ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("resources", locale);

while (true) {
    String key = sc.nextLine();
    if (key.equals("stop"))
        break;

    System.out.println(rb.getString(key));
}
```

Comment: все равно падает с той же ошибкой. Да и условие такое что ключ и локаль нужно ввести последовательно через пробел

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего вы получили ошибку

> java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name
>   resources, locale ru

Проблема в том, что по-умолчанию файлы ищутся в папке resources, а вы положили в корне.

Вам необходимо перенести данный файл в папку *src/main/resources*. Тогда все заработает.

Comment: По умолчанию ресурсы ищутся в classpath, который по умолчанию как раз равен текущей рабочей директории.